# How can I fix my kick command for my Discord bot?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

When I type "exp kick @user being toxic", it doesn't respond with anything: it simply ignores my command. Here is my code:

```
client.on("message", message => {
    var command = message.content.toLowerCase().split("")[0]
    if(command == prefix + "kick"){
        if(message.guild.member(message.author).hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS"))
        return message.channel.send("Please Check Your Permissions")
        if(!message.guild.memeber(client.user).hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS"))
        return message.channel.send("Please Check My Permissions")
        const user = message.mentions.user.first()
        if(!user) return message.channel.send("I can't find this user!")
        const reason = message.content.split(" ").slice(2).join(" ")
        if(!reason) return message.channel.send("Please state the reason for kick!")
        if(message.guild.memeber(user).kickable) return message.channel.send("This user seems to have persmissions which got in the way")
        message.guild.member(user).kick({reason: reason})
        return message.channel.send("Kicked the filthy member `@"+user.tag+"` ")

    }
})
```

Comment: You tagged with "java", but this isn't java code.

Comment: If it would be java, using == to compare strings would definitely not work

Comment: what is your "prefix"? Is it "exp" ? Because "exp" + "kick" --> "expkick" not "exp kick"

Comment: It’s not in java my friend

Comment: It was @MohammedNidhal [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63738212/revisions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a bunch of typos, honestly... I fixed it and it should be working, below are the parts which you messed up in, and the one below that is the fix I made. I had to make it neater because I can barely read it.

---

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    var command = message.content.toLowerCase().split("")[0]
    if(command == prefix + "kick"){
        if(message.guild.member(message.author).hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS"))
        // ^ You forgot to add `!`
        return message.channel.send("Please Check Your Permissions")
        // Putting return like this can sometimes end up breaking your code. Put it without space.
        if(!message.guild.memeber(client.user).hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS"))
        //                ^^^^^^^ The correct spelling is `member`
        return message.channel.send("Please Check My Permissions")
        const user = message.mentions.user.first()
        //                            ^^^^ It's `users` not `user`
        if(!user) return message.channel.send("I can't find this user!")
        const reason = message.content.split(" ").slice(2).join(" ")
        if(!reason) return message.channel.send("Please state the reason for kick!")
        if(message.guild.memeber(user).kickable) return message.channel.send("This user seems to have persmissions which got in the way")
        // ^ Kickable returns true if the bot can kick it, while false if it can't, add `!`
        //               ^^^^^^^ Again with the wrong spelling
        message.guild.member(user).kick({reason: reason})
        return message.channel.send("Kicked the filthy member `@"+user.tag+"` ")
        //                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Use "<@" + user.id + ">" instead to mention.
    }
})
```

---

```js
client.on("message", message => {
  var command = message.toLowerCase().split(" ")[0];
// Add one space to split to split string to individual array variables
  if(command == prefix + "kick") {
    const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    const reason = message.content.split(" ").slice(2).join(" ");
    if(!message.guild.member(message.author).hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("Please Check Your Permissions")
    if(!message.guild.member(client.user).hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("Please Check My Permissions");
    if (!user) return message.channel.send("I can't find this user!");
    if (!reason) return message.channel.send("Please state the reason for kick!");
    if (!message.guild.member(user).kickable) return message.channel.send("This user seems to have permissions which got in the way");
    message.guild.member(user).kick({reason: reason});
    return message.channel.send("Kicked the filthy member <@" + user.id + ">");
  }
})
```

---

Comment: the first line is giving me an error @Mineko Kayui. but thanks. i did not see these stuff.

Comment: The first line? `var command = message.toLowerCase().split(" ")[0];`? It's because you forgot to put space in `.split("")` I fixed it in the answer.

Comment: no i mean. in the answer. that code's first line, "var command = message.toLowerCase().split(" ")[0];" is telling me "ReferenceError: message is not defined"

Comment: Did you not add the `client.on("message", message => {})`? I did not include it in the answer because it doesn't have a problem... Okay, I revised it again.

Comment: You're welcome @NumberedBore7^^ Can you also please mark this as the correct answer with the checkmark? It would be helpful :)

Comment: i think i did it? sorry for late reply also

Comment: Thank you, I don't mind the late reply, good luck on your projects.